# correctly pass parameters to export of a dll using rundll32

Tags: windows, dll, dllexport, rundll32

Here is code of export function of a DLL that just adds two number and prints it to a MessageBox.

```
int Add(int a, int b)
```

{

```
OutputDebugString(L"add function called");

int sum = 0;
sum = a + b;
```

// MessageBoxA();

```
char buf[10];
_itoa(sum, buf, 10);
MessageBoxA(NULL, buf, "Caption", MB_OK);
```

When I pass the parameters to the exported function using rundll32 (command rundll32 dllName,Add 2 3), I get some junk number popped up in messagebox. But when I use Olldebugger to debug, I get the expected result which is the sum of numbers.

How do I correctly pass the parameters to the DLL export using rundll32?